Access Denied while sending email from AWS SES in ElasticBeanstalk (Django application)
I have recently (noticed) that I'm getting the following error in my Django application running on AWS

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetSendQuota
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::123412341234:user/USER-IAM-NAME is not
authorized to perform: ses:GetSendQuota with an explicit deny in an
identity-based policy

My user has full SES access via the direct policy AmazonSESFullAccess.
In order to ensure GetSendQuota is explicitly stated, I have also added this inline policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail",
                "ses:GetSendQuota"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I do not understand how to fix this.  Help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT
This issue started on October 2nd.  I can see emails on that date and not after.  No system changes were made at that time
EDIT 2
I've seen the AWS added an SES deny to AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2 on October 2nd which is when this started failing.  Obviously I do not want to remove that policy so I'm trying to add a policy for my specific user to allow access.  How do I do this?

with an explicit deny in an identity-based policy means there's a Deny statement in the iam user/role you use, you should check there

There is no deny in the user and the user isn't assigned a role.  I have simply added permissions directly to the user

I have added AmazonSESFullAccess to the ElasticBeanstalk service role, but continue to get the issue

"I've seen the AWS added an SES deny to AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2 on October 2nd " If that happened, then AWS detected that your AWS keys were compromised and blocked them from being used. According to the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2.html there should also be a support case in your AWS account related to the issue.

There was, but there isn't anything in it about what to do following their change on October 2nd
